# What is "football field" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've tried to find a proper word for this. Any suggestions? Something that works for other sports too would be extra appreciated.

Comment: Piedpilka kampo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Piedpilka kampo* aŭ *futbalkampo*.  *Ludkampo* ĝenerale.